# not able to select radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I am having this strange issue with the radio buttons. I am using custom styles for the radio buttons(with the help of some online tutorials). I am not able to select few options. Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/bm6Lfhdz/1/

Try to select 'Yes' from the second question or 'option 1' from the Fifth question. Nothing happens when you click on them. Can anyone point me whats wrong with the code?

Custom css I am using:

```
div.questions {
margin-bottom: 12px;
border: 1px dotted #fafafa;
padding: 25px 20px;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type='radio'] {
 display: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='radio']:focus, input[type='radio']:active{
  outline: none;
 }
input[type='radio']:hover + label:hover {
  color: #fff; 
}
input[type='radio'] + label {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
 color: #0b4c6a;
}
input[type='radio'] + label:before, input[type='radio'] + label:after{
 content: '';
 font-family: helvetica;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 }
input[type='radio'] + label:before {
 background-color: #fafafa;
 -moz-transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out;
}
input[type='radio'] + label:after {
 color: #fff;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + label:before {
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #4DD26D;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #4DD26D;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #4DD26D;  
}

/*Radio Specific styles*/
input[type='radio'] + label:before {
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
 input[type='radio'] + label:hover:after, input[type='radio']:checked + label:after {
 content: "\2713";
 line-height: 18px;
 font-size: 14px; 
 }
 }
 input[type='radio'] + label:hover:after {
  color: #c7c7c7;
 }
 input[type='radio']:checked + label:after, input[type='radio']:checked + label:hover:after {
 color: #fff;
 }
```

Thanks in advance,

Note: please test all the options. Because I saw some random behavior with the radio button selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each row of questions uses the same ID values for its `<input>` fields. In HTML, the ID needs to be unique on the page.

I guess the browser is confused and thinks that since id="radio1" was already set, it shouldn't have to select it again, even though it's a different element.

If you give all of the input fields a unique id, the problem will go away.

Comment: thanks for the response. Looks like the ID is the issue. I will test it out now.